# Errores al Incluir Páginas PHP como Módulos en mi index.php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, permisos, servidor

espero me puedan sacar de una duda que al parecer es simple, pero prefiero asegurarme.

Les comento, tengo un index.php que incluye distintas secciones con "include". Estas otras secciones son los módulos que están en otra carpeta llamada "secciones_comunes".

El index funciona sin ningún problema, pero si voy a la dirección de ese módulo incluído "../secciones_comunes/navbar.php", me aparecen los errores de variables indefinidas, lo cual tiene sentido porque no están definidas en esa página, están definidas en el index y en otro módulo que se incluye. Ante esto, tengo la duda de como evitar que alguien llegue a esa página, o si por otro lado estoy haciendo lo correcto. Vale mencionar que hay conexiones a la base de datos igualmente, por lo cual proteger estos archivos sería primordial.

Entonces, ¿lo estoy haciendo bien?, ¿cometí un error y no se hace así?, ¿hay alguna mejor manera de hacer esto?, o ¿así se hace y basta con cambiarle los permisos a estos módulos más pequeños en el servidor para evitar problemas de seguridad?

De ante mano, muchas gracias, saludos y perdón si es algo muy básico.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mi_pagina in C:\wamp\www\SystemEvents\php\pages\secciones_comunes\navbar.php
```

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo y el mensaje del error

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Aqui te dejo una guía de cómo deberían ser los ejemplos: [mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @simon Hola estimado, acabo de redactar nuevamente la publicación, saludos y gracias.

Comment: @Julio Muchas gracias por tu comentario, leeré la información pertinente.

Comment: El archivo navbar.php está en 
C:\wamp\www\SystemEvents\php\pages\secciones_comunes\? De lo contrario, podrías mostrarnos tu estructura de archivos, mostrando dónde están index.php y navbar.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una práctica usual (aunque no es la única ni mucho menos) es tener una carpeta `public` desde donde se sirven los archivos que un visitante puede llamar directamente. En tu caso si el `index.php` estuviese en `C:\wamp\www\SystemEvents\php\pages\`, podrías modificar tu estructura para dejar algo como:

```
 - pages
   |__public
   |  |_ index.php
   |
   |__secciones_comunes
      |__navbar.php
```

Y dejar como `document_root` el subdirectorio `public` en vez de `pages`.

De esa manera, el visitante no puede cargar directamente nada que no esté dentro de `public`, pero internamente los scripts sí pueden hacer `include` o `require` mediante la ruta relativa `../secciones_comunes/navbar.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma podria ser que uses una constante en el primer modulo.
p.ej

```
define('ALGO', 1);
```

y en la entrada de los php que no deben ejecutarse directamente:

```
if (!defined('ALGO')) die;
```

es mejor que usar isset, por que las variables cambian todo el tiempo y se crean nuevas.